# How to access the webpage in Nginx docker container from outside the host machine using publicIp of host?

Tags: docker, nginx, networking, containers, host

I am new to docker networking and i am not able to figure out why i cant access the webpage for nginx container hosted in a linux machine as host. if i try to access it from other machine such a windows machine using a public ip, it doesnt connect. Am i missin something here?

this is my `docker network inpsect bridge`

````
``` [
{
    "Name": "bridge",
    "Id": "fcf42bd67c4104ec2f58a57a7db7fe3b623938cc4ece696dfd04a6ff5ab122c9",
    "Created": "2021-09-19T10:50:12.231201531+05:30",
    "Scope": "local",
    "Driver": "bridge",
    "EnableIPv6": false,
    "IPAM": {
        "Driver": "default",
        "Options": null,
        "Config": [
            {
                "Subnet": "172.17.0.0/16",
                "Gateway": "172.17.0.1"
            }
        ]
    },
    "Internal": false,
    "Attachable": false,
    "Ingress": false,
    "ConfigFrom": {
        "Network": ""
    },
    "ConfigOnly": false,
    "Containers": {
        "3d0a83398f1672da98a38d8962e0edba56d726c901a1f01e3593328b29fac191": {
            "Name": "nginx2",
            "EndpointID": "2e764b0a1269128b784f3d9b0bc9c9a97165b09c46ae4b666613fa84b82cdad9",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
            "IPv4Address": "172.17.0.2/16",
            "IPv6Address": ""
        }
    },
    "Options": {
        "com.docker.network.bridge.default_bridge": "true",
        "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_icc": "true",
        "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_ip_masquerade": "true",
        "com.docker.network.bridge.host_binding_ipv4": "0.0.0.0",
        "com.docker.network.bridge.name": "docker0",
        "com.docker.network.driver.mtu": "1500"
    },
    "Labels": {}
}
````

] ```

this is my `docker conatiner ls -a`

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS                      PORTS     NAMES
3d0a83398f16   nginx     "/docker-entrypoint.…"   13 minutes ago   Up 13 minutes               80/tcp    nginx2
bc563e57ba2b   nginx     "/docker-entrypoint.…"   26 minutes ago   Exited (0) 15 minutes ago             confident_yonath
```

Comment: try to publish ports by `docker run -p 80:80 ...` command, it should be accessible on port 80 of host

Comment: None of the `docker network inspect` output is useful to you; those IP addresses won't be reachable from off-host at all.  How are you starting the container?  What URL are you trying to connect to?  What result do you get?

Comment: the container is started using docker container run command and i published ports as 80 on the host. Off host i am accessing using the public ip of the host machine and the port number. http://<public_ip_of_host>:80
PS: My host is a linux machine running on a VM ware